# How can I get polymer

Tags: polymer

I have tow repos(A and B, B depends on A).Now A has been upgrade to Polymer@3 and B still use Polymer@2.
I use `import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';` in A and `class AgeSwitch extends Polymer.Element` in B.
Before upgrating to Polymer@3,B can get `Polymer` by A.But now it is undefinded.How can I get `Polymer` or `PolymerElement`?Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried importing 'polymer-element.html' from bower components in your 'B'?

Comment: if I imported 'polrmer-element.html', the polymer which is in A will be error